# UItable View cell with textLabel , detailTextLabel and UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uitableview

I'm implementing a table view controller for my view. As the specific detail in apple docs, I used `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle` for my cell in the table.

What I need is a cell contain a small avatar on the left, the bold `textLabel` and a smaller `detailTextLabel`. Both `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel` are multiple lines, not one line only.

I'm trying with the tutorial from the [link](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/11/18/making-smarter-table-view-cells/), but the simulator only show the `textLabel`.

Here is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
cell.textLabel.text = [newsTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = ceilf([[newsTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap].height/20);

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [newsDescription objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = ceilf([[newsTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap].height/20);
return cell;
}
```

Here is the `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSString *titleString = [newsTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *detailString = [newsDescription objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    CGSize titleSize = [titleString sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    CGSize detailSize = [detailString sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    return detailSize.height+titleSize.height;

}
```

**Note:** the array `newsTitle` keep the content of `textLabel`, `newsDescription` for `textDetailLabel`. It not contains the avatar yet. I greatly appreciate if someone can help me to fix this problem and also add the smaller avatar to this table view cell.

Comment: also u have to set height of textLabel & detailTextLabel in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method..

Comment: do you get solution or not?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass that has a property for a `UIImageView` that you can populate with the `UIImage` of your choosing in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.  I would suggest adding the `UIImageView` as a subview of the `contentView` and then adjusting the cell's indentation to be the width of the `UIImageView` plus some padding.  This has the effect of moving the entire contents of the cell to the right to make space for your image:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    if (self) {
        // make room for the icon
        self.indentationLevel = 1;
        self.indentationWidth = kIconWidth + kIconPadding;

        _iconImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(kIconPadding, kIconPadding, kIconWidth, kIconWidth)];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_iconImageView];
    }

    return self;
}
```